# cannot catch segmentation fault second time

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to restart the program when segmention fault occures.

I have following minimal reproducible code:-

```cpp
#include <csignal>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int app();

void ouch(int sig) {
    std::cout << "got signal " << sig << std::endl;
    exit(app());
}

struct L { int l; };
static int i = 0;

int app() {
    L *l= nullptr;
    while(1) {
        std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << l->l << std::endl; //crash
        std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = ouch;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGKILL, &act, 0);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0);
    return app();
}
```

It successfully catches sigsegv first time but after it prints 2, it shows me segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
1
got signal 11
2
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

tested with clang 12.0.1 and gcc 11.1.0 on ArchLinux

Is this operating system specific behavior or is something wrong in my code

Comment: It seems you don't understand for what signal handlers are used. If a signal is raised from a signal handler, it's bad.

Comment: Possible remedy in [Why can't I ignore SIGSEGV signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8456519/7582247)

Comment: Trying to recover from a segfault is almost always a very bad idea. It isn't designed to be a recoverable error, it usually indicates a logic error which is something that can't be fixed at runtime.

Comment: You should really think the other way around and be grateful for the segfault. It means your program has a bug in it that needs to be solved. Don't add new code until you've solved the root cause of this one.

Comment: You can `siglongjmp` to try to get back to some known point in the program, but global state may be messed up, and you may also leak memory or other resources.  Or you can `exec()` to start completely from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you restart the program by calling `exit(app())` from inside `ouch()`, you are still technically inside the signal handler. The signal handler is blocked until you return from it. Since you never return, you therefore cannot catch a second SIGSEGV.

If you got a SIGSEGV, then something really bad has happened, and there is no guarantee that you can just "restart" the process by calling `app()` again.
The best solution to handle this is to have another program start your program, and restart it if it crashed. See [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/52976/simple-way-of-restarting-crashed-processes) for some suggestions of how to handle this.